# Getting class instance from other project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container

I have a class library with a class like this:

```
public class GoogleSearch
{
    private IGoogleApiHelper _googleApiHelper;

    public GoogleSearch(IGoogleApiHelper googleApiHelper)
    {
        _googleApiHelper = googleApiHelper;
    }
    //some methods
}
```

googleApiHelper is a service got from IoC container of the library.
Can I create an instance of GoogleSearch class from outside of library and make googleApiHelper service to be taken from IoC container?

Comment: I referenced it to project and want to invoke a method of it. The problem is that I have to pass an instance of IGoogleApiHelper in constructor, but I want it to be taken from IoC container

Comment: If you want to create new instance of `GoogleSearch`, then you might use dependency resolver to get `IGoogleApiHelper` and pass it. Or you might think of resolving `GoogleSearch` also using dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> googleApiHelper is a service got from IoC container of the library.

Prevent doing this. Libraries should not use a DI Container, only the start-up project should have a reference to the DI Container and should make all the required registration, including the types that are part of your library. For more information, read about the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

If you follow the Composition Root pattern, you won't have any problems, since everything is composed in that single place.